# How can I format an etude book and use my custom header using lilypond?

Tags: lilypond

I am creating several etude books and would like to be able to use the custom header I've developed. The code for the header I use for solo and other works looks like this:

```
evenHeaderMarkup = \markup { 
\fill-line {
  \center-column {
    \line { \on-the-fly #not-part-first-page \override #'(font-name . "Libre Franklin Light") \fromproperty #'header:piece }
    \line {
      \on-the-fly #not-part-first-page \override #'(font-name . "Libre Franklin Light") \fromproperty #'header:instrument \override #'(font-name . "Libre Franklin Light") "- PG." \override #'(font-name . "Libre Franklin Light") \on-the-fly #print-page-number-check-first \fromproperty #'page:page-number-string }}}}
```

This is so the header will look like this:

[image: my custom header]

Each \score block to this etude book will have it's own piece and instrument:

[image: score block example with individual piece and intrument]

Where I am getting stuck is I do not know how to format this project as an etude book. Ideally, the code for the entire etude book output will be in one file of code, with the book having a title, and each \score block also would have a specific title, piece and instrument. I would then call that specific information from each individual \score block into the header for each individual etude contained in the book.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Could you say more about what are you exactly having problems with? It seems to me that you have done everything correctly. You can either put the individual `\scores` one after another, or put them all in a `\book` construct. Was that the fact you were missing?

Comment: The problem that I am having is that it isn't working. If I designate a "piece" in a \header block inside of a \score block, that piece does not appear in the custom header of the page.

Comment: Apparently, you have to put each score in a separate book part. That's the best I could get -> http://lilybin.com/8w3o4q/1

Answer (score 1):

you need to be using \book and \bookpart . Set up things that repeat like fonts and text strings as globals or variables.